# Using sqlSave to save a dataframe into a different database

Tags: sql-server, r, rodbc

I am trying to save a data.frame called "MyDF" in to a table called "MyTable" in a database called "database2".  The channel "con" opens a connection to a different database on the same server.  I have several attempts below where I try to write back to database2 on the server and get errors.

In Attempt1 the code creates an empty table called MyTable in the correct database database2, and then throws the error below.

The final attempt, Attempt7 creates a table and loads the records in to it, but creates it on the wrong database.

Is it possible to create a table on database2 and load the records from MyDF in to it using channel con, or do I need to create a new channel specifically to database2?  I never have any trouble pulling data from database2 using channel con and sqlQuery, as long as I just add [database2].[dbo] to the beginning of the table name.

```
Attempt1:
sqlSave(con,MyDF,tablename="[database2].[dbo].[MyTable]",fast=F,append=F)

Error in sqlColumns(channel, tablename) : 
‘[database2].[dbo].[MyTable]’: table not found on channel

 Attempt2:

 sqlSave(con,MyDF,tablename="[database2].[dbo].[MyTable]",fast=F,append=T)

 Error in sqlSave(con, MyDF, tablename = "[database2].[dbo].[MyTable]",  : 
 42S01 2714 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'MyTable' in the database.
 [RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE [database2].[dbo].[MyTable]  ("rownames" varchar(255), "Field1" float, "Field2" float, "Field3" float, "Field4" float, "Field5" float, "Field6" float, "Field7" float, "Field8" float, "Field9" float, "Field10" float, "Field11" float, "Field12" float, "Field13" float, "Field14" varchar(255))'


 Attempt3:

 sqlSave(con,MyDF,tablename="[database2].[dbo].[MyTable]",fast=T,append=T)

 Error in sqlSave(con, MyDF, tablename = "[database2].[dbo].[MyTable]",  : 
 42S01 2714 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'MyTable' in the database.
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE [database2].[dbo].[MyTable]  ("rownames" varchar(255), "Field1" float, "Field2" float, "Field3" float, "Field4" float, "Field5" float, "Field6" float, "Field7" float, "Field8" float, "Field9" float, "Field10" float, "Field11" float, "Field12" float, "Field13" float, "Field14" varchar(255))'

Attempt4:

sqlSave(con,MyDF,tablename="[database2].[dbo].[MyTable]", verbose=TRUE, rownames= FALSE)
Query: CREATE TABLE [database2].[dbo].[MyTable]  ("Field1" float, "Field2" float, "Field3" float, "Field4" float, "Field5" float, "Field6" float, "Field7" float, "Field8" float, "Field9" float, "Field10" float, "Field11" float, "Field12" float, "Field13" float, "Field14" varchar(255))
Error in sqlSave(con, MyDF, tablename = "[database2].[dbo].[MyTable]",  : 
42S01 2714 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'MyTable' in the database.
[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE [database2].[dbo].[MyTable]  ("Field1" float, "Field2" float, "Field3" float, "Field4" float, "Field5" float, "Field6" float, "Field7" float, "Field8" float, "Field9" float, "Field10" float, "Field11" float, "Field12" float, "Field13" float, "Field14" varchar(255))'


Attempt5:

sqlSave(con,MyDF,tablename="[database2].[dbo].[MyTable]", verbose=TRUE, rownames= FALSE,fast=T,append=T)

Query: CREATE TABLE [database2].[dbo].[MyTable]  ("Field1" float, "Field2" float, "Field3" float, "Field4" float, "Field5" float, "Field6" float, "Field7" float, "Field8" float, "Field9" float, "Field10" float, "Field11" float, "Field12" float, "Field13" float, "Field14" varchar(255))
Error in sqlSave(con, MyDF, tablename = "[database2].[dbo].[MyTable]",  : 
42S01 2714 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]There is already an object named 'MyTable' in the database.
```

[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'CREATE TABLE [database2].[dbo].[MyTable]  ("Field1" float, "Field2" float, "Field3" float, "Field4" float, "Field5" float, "Field6" float, "Field7" float, "Field8" float, "Field9" float, "Field10" float, "Field11" float, "Field12" float, "Field13" float, "Field14" varchar(255))'

```
  Attempt6:

  sqlUpdate(con,MyDF,tablename="[database2].[dbo].[MyTable]")
 Error in odbcTableExists(channel, tablename) : 
 ‘[database2].[dbo].[MyTable]’: table not found on channel


 Attempt7:

 sqlSave(con,MyDF,tablename="MyTable",fast=F,append=F)
```

Comment: Do you have permission to write to database2?

Comment: @HongOoi Thank you for responding, yes I have permission to write to database2.  Also in the first attempt it creates the table in database2, but doesn't append any records.

Comment: Try opening a new connection to database2, rather than piggybacking on the original database.